# How can I view the javascript bundle code in React Native?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, babeljs

I have a `React Native 0.57.8` project that uses TypeScript and Babel 7.

I would like to see the javascript code that is in the bundle so I can see what TypeScript and Babel have modified. Specifically, I am trying to see how TS and Babel handle default parameters for a class constructor.

I am aware the TS will add `this.parameter = parameter` to a class constructor body if the constructor parameters are given a modifier such as public, private, or readonly, but I don't know if `this.parameter = parameter` is added to the beginning of the constructor body, or end of the constructor body.

Is there a way I can view the javascript output that TS and Babel create?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can generate the bundle yourself and then inspect it.

Either visit the Metro Bundler url when it's running on a terminal, e.g.
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false.

(This might require a full generation if it's not cached already, so it can take a while).

Or just generate a static file through the command line:

```
// iOS
npx react-native bundle --entry-file=index.js --bundle-output='./bundle.js' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios' --reset-cache
// Android
npx react-native bundle --entry-file=index.js --bundle-output='./bundle.js' --dev=false --platform='android' --assets-dest='./android/app/src/main/res' --reset-cache
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I used the Metro Bundler url and I was able to find the code I was looking for easily. It took about 5 minutes to load, but it worked great!

Comment: Also, I was able to see that TypeScript puts the this.parameter = parameter statements at the beginning of the constructor body. Any other statements in the constructor body come after.

Comment: The two commands will fail if you do `--platform='ios'` or `--platform='android'`. Remove the quotes for the commands to work: `--platform=ios` or `platform=android`.

Comment: do you know the way to inspect the `index.android.bundle` extracted from apk? I am using `react-native-obfuscation` and need to check if my setup is correct..